# ROS executable without Boost dependency

Tags: boost, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to  create a ROS executable (where the executable is a target of type `executable` within a CMakeLists.txt which is created with catkin and the c++ files include `ros/ros.h`) that does not link to boost? If I have an executable `program` and do `ldd program` there occurs at least a dependency on:
`libboost_system.so.1.58.0 libboost_thread.so.1.58.0`

Is it possible to avoid these?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297928/ros-executable-without-boost-dependency/) by [mherrmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/35231/mherrmann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2018-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No. It is possible in ROS 2, but not in ROS 1 as the dependency to boost is directly in the `roscpp` library: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/search?q=boost&unscoped_q=boost

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0